# Numba - how can I extract a value from a multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

I'm using numba and numpy to write a function, and in the course of my function, I will compute these two items: `idx`, which is a list of coordinates (for example, `idx = [3,4,5]`), and `values`, a 3d numpy array (for example, `values.shape` will yield `(100, 100, 100)`). Note that the dimension of `values` can change arbitrarily.

Normally, if I do `values[3,4,5]`, it will return a number, which is the value at the coordinate indicated. However, if I do `values[idx]`, I get an array! I know that this works: `values[tuple(idx)]`, but this will throw an error in numba:

```
TypingError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>
```

I cannot make `idx` a tuple to start with, because `idx` is created in a for loop which appends elements to `idx`, which is defined to be an empty list before the loop.

Is there a simple way to extract a value from a 3d numpy array given a list, which has the coordinates in each of the dimensions? This seemingly easy problem is incredibly hard to solve.

This is a minimally replicable function:

```
gridMat = (np.linspace(1, 3, 100), np.linspace(0,2,100), 
        np.linspace(5, 6,100))
mGrid = np.meshgrid(*gridMat, indexing = 'ij')
values = np.power(mGrid[0], 2) + mGrid[1] / 4.0 + 3.0 + mGrid[2] * 4

@jit(nopython=True)
def testFunction(values):
    idx = []
    N = 3
    for n in range(N):
        idx.append(n + 1)

    idx_res = tuple(idx)

    print(values[idx_res])
```

Comment: It would help if you post the exact error you get when you do `values[tuple(idx)]`.

Comment: values[idx[0], idx[1], idx[2]] ? It wouldn't scale very well with the length of idx, but it seems that idx is fixed size?

Comment: @fferri added the error.

Comment: What's stopping you from defining `idx` as a tuple in the first place?

Comment: @MadPhysicist ```idx``` is created through an iterative process by ```appending``` values to ```idx``` which starts out as an empty list. Tuples are immutable.

Comment: Now I'm starting to think that error is shady. Can you post some minimal code that actually reproduces it?

Comment: @tryingtosolve. `idx += (5,)`. It will be only marginally less efficient than `list.append` for short tuples.

Comment: Oh, and could you please add the full stack trace of your error along with the code?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Added a replicable example.

Comment: `tuple(range(1, N + 1))`?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody is answering I'll post my comment as an answer:

Is there something wrong with `values[idx[0], idx[1], idx[2]]` ? For larger `idx` it would be impractical, but it seems that `values.shape[0]` is fixed and equal to 3, so this basic solution looks like the way to go for me.

Otherwise, the solution which come to mind is to loop over the dims and access the element of a flattened view of values:

```
offset = 1
for d in range(values.ndim):
    offset *= idx[d] * values.strides[d]
element = values.flat[offset]
```

(also you need to divide strides by 8 if your dtype is float64)
but this is not very pretty... Do you know how `strides` and `flat` work?

Comment: Sorry! The dimensions can change. Updated the post.

Comment: This sounds like overkill because I'm pretty sure the question is missing some crucial info.